# How can I hide the cursor in ncurses?

Tags: ncurses

I am writing `ncurses` programs in C and C++. I have not found a way to conceal the cursor to the user. I have looked around on the internet a bit, but most of the information that I have found either concerns Python/Ruby implementations of (n)curses or doesn't actually concern the hiding of the cursor. How may I accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

You need [`curs_set(0)`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xcurses/curs_set.html)

To quote the man page (with some added formatting):

> The `curs_set` routine sets the cursor state to invisible, normal, or very visible for visibility equal to 0, 1, or 2 respectively.  If the terminal supports the visibility requested, the  previous cursor state is returned; otherwise, `ERR` is returned.

Comment: Thanks! just so we know :)  `import curses` then `curses.curs_set(0)`